# Giving a pressed effect to a button without using an external image

Tags: android, android-button

I want to give a pressed effect on normal button in the selector tag. I am not using a new image for the button. i am using the normal button provided by android.
Can that effect be provided without using an external image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to take a look at [android statelist](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#StateList) where you will have to define the state of the object at each state. For instance, if it's pressed change the bg color. That is the closest way I could think of without using images.

Comment: Yeah that is a good idea.I will try that. But is there not any fnality in android to give a pressed effect.

Comment: So far, I'm not sure there is a direct way to do so.